# Terraform import default dhcp & main route table id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

is there a way to manage default resources of aws with `import` command, when it has been created and the ids are saved into `terraform.tfstate`, I would like to add a tags to those resources.

Comment: Which "default resources"? Like default VPC?

Comment: No, the DHCP, when my Terraform is creating a VPC, there are default DHCP, and Route Table (Main), they have no name, and they're forcing me to manage those name tags via aws console manually

Comment: If you want to manage your VPC's main route table, terraform provides dedicated resource for that in the form of [aws_main_route_table_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/main_route_table_association). Not sure if this is what you are after?

Comment: I'm aware of that module, but if you look to my question, I want to change the tags, the resource aws_main_route_table_association does not provide such option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add tags to ec2 resources, including main route table, you should use [aws_ec2_tag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_tag).

For example, the below code creates a VPC and **adds a tag to its main route table**:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.1.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name = "myvpc"
  }
}


resource "aws_ec2_tag" "mytag" {
  resource_id = aws_vpc.vpc.main_route_table_id
  key         = "Name"
  value       = "Hello World"
}
```